Does every nontrivial arithmetic consequence of large cardinal have large cardinal strength?
Suppose $\varphi$ is an arithmetic sentence (statement about natural numbers) that is not provable in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ but provable in, say, $\mathsf{ZFC}+$"there exists an inaccessible cardinal". Does $\mathsf{ZFC}+\varphi$ have higher consistency strength than $\mathsf{ZFC}$? If not is there anything true along these lines? If I understand correctly, this should be true if $\varphi$ is $\Pi_1$.
Of course we don't consider arbitrary $\varphi$. For example, measurable cardinal proves $V\neq L$, which doesn't have consistency strength.

Another example would be the Rosser sentence for ZFC.

Consider, for instance, the sentence $\varphi=\mathsf{Con(ZFC)\to Con(ZFC+\mathsf{Con}(ZFC))}$.  Then $\varphi$ is not provable in ZFC (unless ZFC proves its own inconsistency), since if it were, then $\mathsf{ZFC+\mathsf{Con}(ZFC)}$ would prove its own consistency.  However, $\mathsf{ZFC}+\varphi$ has the same consistency strength as ZFC, since if ZFC is consistent then it has a model where $\mathsf{Con(ZFC)}$ is false so $\varphi$ is true.
